# Mercurial: hg-checklinks- recursive symlink over NFS/SAMBA/SSHFS network drive

Tags: macos, mercurial, sshfs

When I macfusion into my ubuntu VM, and hg clone something from bitbucket - and then try and do a commit / export / etc on it, I get a folder added with a name prefix of 'hg-checklinks-'.

On inspection it appears to house a never ending chain of symlinks back to its parent folder. This is driving me completely nuts, and so far, I've lost my faith in mercurial.

Mind you, seems to work fine when I just use it on a local folder. Does anyone have any idea how I can get around this.. or even more info as to why it's happening?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *decentralized* part of DVCS is about running it locally -- the only Mercurial operations that should be done on anything other than the local system are `push`, `pull`, and `clone`.  If you're cloning from bitbucket onto your Ubuntu VM then you should clone from your Ubuntu VM onto your mac and push to the Ubuntu VM.

That said, it looks like your network FS isn't correctly deleting the file when it's told to.  Here's the relevant code (found here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/a2dc8819bb0d/mercurial/util.py#l710):

```
name = tempfile.mktemp(dir=path, prefix='hg-checklink-')
try:
    os.symlink(".", name)
    os.unlink(name)
    return True
except (OSError, AttributeError):
    return False
```

So either your network FS is creating the symlink but throwing an exception anyway or throwing an exception when asked to delete (unlink) the symlink.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for that  - really informative. Not sure what to do about the network FS. Good about about cloning the Ubuntu repos, but obviously that means whenever I make a change to a file and want to preview it, I've got to then do a push - which isn't so fun.

Comment: Like I've said, I've tried NFS, Samba & SSHFS. The problem only happens when I commit. It'd be good to figure out a way around this :(

Comment: I suspect putting `os.unlink(name)` after the `except` line and before the `return False` will stop that file from showing up, but who knows what other wrongness your fuse layer might be injecting that's not as readily visible.  The only safe action is to modify your workflow to push/pull over the network and commit locally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with sshfs's very special "-o follow_symlinks", which will happily create symlinks, then claim it couldn't create them, then show them as awesome recursive unremovable directories. This broken option may automatically be turned on by a bug in Macfusion (https://code.google.com/p/macfusion/issues/detail?id=284). So if anything, you should "lose faith" in sshfs and Macfusion, not Mercurial.

This will be worked around in Mercurial 2.7. In the meantime, you should be able to run sshfs manually without the option.

(For faster bug fixes, please report bugs to the Mercurial/sshfs/macfusion projects, not random internet question forums.)